# How to update Boolean Value in Flask SQLAlchemy

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am currently using this code

```
update = user.query.filter_by(uid=id).update(dict(approved=True))
usr.session.commit()
```

But it gives this as error:

[image]

**UPDATE**

**USER MODEL**

```
usr = SQLAlchemy(app)
Class user(usr.Model):
    index = usr.Column(usr.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    username = usr.Column(usr.String())
    uid = usr.Column(usr.String(8))
    approved = usr.Column(usr.Boolean(), default=None)
```

Comment: Please Upvote the question if you don't know the answer

Comment: Can you show your `User` model?

Comment: I have updated you can see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of this

```
update = user.query.filter_by(uid=id).update(dict(approved=True))
```

Do this

```
update = user.query.filter_by(uid=id).first()
update.approved = True
usr.session.commit()
```

This will Solve your Problem